# uploading files using camera on a moblie device on an ASP.Net web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, flash, mobile, camera

I'm making a website using a using ASP.NET and I which for the user if he is using a mobile device to use it's built-in camera to upload a captured image and pass it to another ASP.NET control 
I doesn't matter wither it's javascript, HTML5 or Flash as long as it works with ASP.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application run inside a browser it is impossible to access the hardware devices such as camera. But you can change your html5 and javascript code into a mobile application which have access to such hardware devices using javascript libraries api like [cordova](http://cordova.apache.org).